# Is there any benefit of indexing columns with duplicate value?

Tags: mysql, sql

We are try to select data with 2 columns in where clause and the problem is 1 column has only 1 value in the whole table and second column has only 1, 3 and 5 values in the whole table of 500 000 rows.

The query is taking more time, so if I index on those both columns, will it give better performance? I do have some idea that columns with low cardinality will have bad performance. But is there any chance to get any better performance?

Comment: "1 column is having only one value".  I don't get it.  Why is it in the table?  Why is it in the `WHERE` clause?  Sample data would really help convey what your data looks like.

Comment: "certainly have bad performance" - why?  You should add indexes to columns that appear in WHERE clauses.  Do these columns appear in any?  If not, adding indexes won't help anything.

Comment: One column is having value as "taxcal" in the whole table and other row with "1","3" and "5"

Comment: And also sorting the output with the column that is having the "taxcal" in whole table

Comment: Low cardinality columns won't yield any performance if indexed, index will almost surely always be ignored. You didn't post the query so it's impossible to know *why* the query takes time, it seems you *think* it might be because of these columns. I have no idea what lakh is, I won't bother finding out, but there are multiple potential reasons why your query is slow - MySQL that's running with default settings, returning entire data-set etc. When asking about query performance, **always** include the query, output of `EXPLAIN` and how many records you got back.

Answer (score 1):

If a column has exactly one value in the table, then indexing it will not do very much.  If you are *only* selecting that value, then scanning an index might be a little faster than scanning the whole table.  But the query doesn't seem very useful.

If a column has only three values, then its selectivity is likely to be poor.  That is, each value has -- roughly -- one third of the records.  In general, if one third of the records have a given value, then a query selecting one of those values will have to read all the data pages.

So, an index would not be very useful.

There are two situations where an index might be useful.  The first is if one of the value is rarer than the others.  So, if "1" appears on only 1 out of 1000 records, then an index should make the query faster when you are looking for "1" values.

The other situation is when the column is the first column in a clustered index.  This will reduce the number of pages that need to be read.  However, clustered indexes on column values (as opposed to identity columns) have other overheads, particularly when inserting or updating values.